# Using a table in another database

Tags: mysql, alias

I've been asked to build a module for a web application, which will also be used as a stand alone website. Since this is the case, I wanted to use a separate database, and wondered if there was a way of having a table in one database, be a "pointer" in another database.

For example, I have databases db1 and db2

db1 has table users, so I want to have db2.users point to db1.users.

I know I could setup triggers and what not to sync two seperate tables but this sounds cooler :)

**EDIT**

So in my code I'm using sql such as

```
select * from users
```

Now, at the database level, I want "users" to actually be db1.users. Then, if I want to, I can remove the alias/pointer and "select * from users" will point to the users table in the current database. I guess what I'm looking for is a "global alias" type of thing.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you are asking, can you be a little bit more specific ?

Comment: I've tried to explain better (view question)

Comment: Can't you just `mysql_select_db('db2'); /*queries*/ mysql_select_db('db1');` ?

Comment: no, thats just a long way of doing what Emmerman suggests

Comment: What is it you need ? This is not like what @Emmerman suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [federated storage engine](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/federated-storage-engine.html) offers something similar to the feature you asked for. 
And if your databases are on the same database server, the federated storage enging sounds a bit like an overkill to me. You may want to [create a view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-view.html) instead.

Both methods won't be useful if db1 is not available. As Emmerman already points out, you need to store the data in db2 if you want to prepare for the case of db1 being unavailable.

Comment: I think you miss my point. I want to be able to just change one line of code at the database level in order for the transfer from module to stand alone. so when i do "select * from users" I can remove the alias and create a table called "users" in db2

Comment: Think you edited the answer? This is the closest method I could find to what i was looking for so thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

Just use it directly from another database?

```
SELECT ... FROM `db1`.`users` LEFT JOIN `db2`.`something`
```

Comment: Well db1 might not necessarily be available when the module becomes a stand alone website, hence I would rather avoid this method

Comment: Then you need a copy of that table, not a 'pointer' (whatever it means).

Comment: Yes but, I don't want to have to change every sql statement in the app . So
select ... from users is changed at the db level from point to db1.users to the users table within the database.